# Java jax-ws client 2 way SSL

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap

I am trying to create JAX-WS client to consume Java service with 2-way SSL auth. I have two .pfx certificates from which one is for signing and one is for transport, and one public key .cer which is for encryption. I made client with wsdl2java tool and keystore .jks with portecle in which i put my certificates. Also I have CA certificate which I put in cacerts in ProgramFiles/Java.../Security/cacerts trust store. When I run my app I got Certificate Unknown response, but everything works ok in SOAP UI with same keystore and certificates. Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C://Program Files//Java//jdk1.8.0_51//jre//lib//security//cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D://workspace//java-workspace//Client//Certifikati//client.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "false");
    //System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages", "false");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
    //System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.dhKeyExchangeFix", "true");


    WsService service = getService();

    MboRequest request = createRequest();
    MboResponse mboResponse = service.getUlosciByMbo(request);
    System.out.println(mboResponse);

}



private static MboRequest createRequest() {
    MboRequest request = new MboRequest();
    request.setDohvatiIpovijesnoStanje(Boolean.FALSE);
    request.setMbo("90445066");
    return request;
}

private static WsService getService() {
    WsService_Service serviceImpl = new WsService_Service();
    return serviceImpl.getWsServiceImplPort();
}

}
```

Here is an error I get:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at org.springframework.www.schema.beans.WsServiceSoapBindingStub.getUlosciByMbo(WsServiceSoapBindingStub.java:588)
        at RunnerClass.main(RunnerClass.java:43)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
        ... 11 more

Can you help me guys to make this client working please.
```

Here are images from SOAP UI

[image: SSL Transport .pfx certificate]

Signature .pfx key(I think this one makes problem in eclipse keystore but works it in SOAP UI? And how to implement binary security token in jax ws client?)

[image]

Encryption with .cer public key.

[image]

Comment: Either the certs you are using in your Java code are not what you think they are, or they are not being set properly in your Java code.  Try commenting out all the `System.setProperty()` calls for SLL and see what error you get.

Comment: I get Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate when I remove comment all properties but everything works in SOAP UI with same keystore.

Comment: Try checking each JKS file on the command line: `keytool -list -v -keystore client.jks`  My current hypothesis is that the files are in a format which your Java code cannot handle, but SOAP UI _can_ handle.

Comment: If I put .cer public key for signing instead of .pfx I get                                                                                                                 Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header